# Mongoose Query resolves even if it wasn't awaited

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following Model:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // long long schema... etc
  age: Number,
})
const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'users')
```

I have the following function:

```js
async function x(y) {
  // @param y: function | asyncfunction
  const YreturnValue = await y()
  YreturnValue.sort('age')
  return YreturnValue // returns a Mongoose Query
}
```

and I have the following route:

```js
router.route('/').get(async (req, res, next) => {
  const query = await x(() => UserModel.find({}))
  const docs = await query 
  res.status(200).json({ data: docs })
})
```

When I request the `GET /`, I get this error:
[image]

I am *awaiting* the function **x** because it's an async function (i.e, it returns a Promise), and the resolved value of the function **x** is **expected** to be a **mongoose Query object**.

- the function **x** receives one argument, a function, or an async function, in both cases, your argument must return a mongoose Query object.

What's the problem?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely correct. You actually awaited your query. You  have `await y()` where y is `() => User.find()`. Therefore `y` is called to return `User.find()` which will finally be evaluated as `await User.find()`. The way `async` functions work is they always return a promise which means as long as `y` returns the query, awaiting `y` will ALWAYS resolve it. One way of solving this is to change the return type of `y` to a `function` that returns the query. If  `y = () => { return () => User.find() }` then after `yReturnVAlue - await y()` return `yReturnVAlue().sort()`

Answer (score -1):

The issue is in the `x` function:

- after the `y` promise is resolved, the `YreturnValue` variable is now an array of documents.
- then you're trying to sort this array by age (`YreturnValue.sort('age')`). **You can't do that this way.** You need to give a comparison function as argument, not a string. See [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#syntax) for syntax.

Comment: _after the y promise is resolved, the YreturnValue variable is now an array of documents._. Ok I don't want it to be an array of documents, how do I make it the query itself?

Comment: the `.sort()` method I'm calling here, I am expecting it to be the [Query.prototype.sort](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-sort) method, not the [JavaScript one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#syntax)